# Fast condition checkup iterating on multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a big ndimensional array. I want to iterate on it to check whether a condition is locally satisfied. Next snippet explains my problem.

```
a = np.random.randint(2, size=(60,80,3,3))

test = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])

for i in xrange(a.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(b.shape[1]):
        if (a[i,j] == test).all():
            # Do something with indices i and j
```

The code is obviously very slow. I tried using `numpy.where` but it's not working as it looks for equality at each of the four indices.

EDIT: I do also need to store the indices `(i,j)` which satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.apply_over_axes(np.prod, a == test, [3,2]) == 1
```

gives you an array of size `(60,80,1,1)` which is `True` whereever the condition holds. A shorter, preferrable version found by the thread starter is

```
(a == test).all(axis=(2,3))
```

Both are equivalent, but the latter avoids the boolean → integer → boolean conversion. Use `np.where` on that array to get the indices `(i, j)`.

Comment: Wow, seems to work. Do you think it is quite the same as `np.where(a == test).all(axis=(2,3)), 1, 0` ? I found this to work either, are at least looks like to.

Comment: You mean `np.where(a == test).all(axis=(2,3))`? Yes, that's equivalent. And looks much better.